# query a fuseki server using python (or something)

Tags: sparql, rdf, fuseki

I'm trying to issue a complicated query against a fuseki server that I'm running locally through a browser but it keeps crashing- is it possible to do it through a python script? If so- how?

Comment: What keeps crashing -- fuseki or your browser? Why do you think python will be a better choice? What have you tried along the python path?

Comment: Likely also worth trying a different browser or two...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use any suitable command line tool, for example `curl`:

`curl http://localhost:3030/your_service/sparql --data 'query=ASK { ?s ?p ?o . }'`

If you want to use Python specifically, you can use [SPARQLWrapper](https://rdflib.github.io/sparqlwrapper/), or just the [Requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org/) package.

Example using Requests:

```
import requests
response = requests.post('http://localhost:3030/your_service/sparql',
       data={'query': 'ASK { ?s ?p ?o . }'})
print(response.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
./s-query --service=http://localhost:3030/myDataset/query --query=/home/matthias/EIS/EDSA/27/18.05/queryFile.rq
```

With the above command it can also work.

Follow the ideas from the [SOH - SPARQL over HTTP page](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/soh.html), i.e.

**SOH SPARQL Query**

```
s-query --service=endpointURL 'query string'

s-query --service=endpointURL --query=queryFile.rq
```