# how to query local fuseki server using python

Tags: sparql, fuseki

I'm New to Fuseki and Sparql.

I was looking at this post --> [query a fuseki server using python (or something)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287656/query-a-fuseki-server-using-python-or-something)
Where one of the solutions was to use `requests`

Here is my code, but the query is unsuccessful!

```
import requests

query = '''
SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object
WHERE {
    GRAPH <ma_graph.ttl>{
        ?subject ?predicate ?object.
    {
}
LIMIT 25
'''

response = requests.post('http://localhost:3030/#/dataset/fusekiservice/query',
                      data={'query': query})
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Successfully accessed the page.")
    try:
        json_response = response.json()
        print(json_response)
    except ValueError:
        print("Response is not in JSON format.")
        print(response.text)
else:
    print(f"Failed to access the page. Status code: {response.status_code}")
```

I get `Failed to access the page. Status code: 405`. The output that I expect to see is a list of 25 triplets.

Usually, I use my local PC to access the fuseki, and I query on this page `http://localhost:3030/#/dataset/fusekiservice/query` with a UI.
However, I'm not sure that I have to request access to that page, and that's what causes the problem.

Edit 1:
As UninformedUser mentioned in the comments I did change the fuseki URL to SPARQL Endpoint that I found in the web UI `/fusekiservice/`, but it didn't help. I also tried /fusekiservice/query and /fusekiservice/sprql

Comment: the Fuseki URL is most likely wrong, that looks the the web UI URL. In the web UI you should also see the query endpoint URL in one of the tabs - use that one. How do run Fuseki? Via an assembler file? I think it should be more `http://localhost:3030/fusekiservice/query`